# Session Expired after closing browser when using State Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies, stateserver

i have a very simple question
I m using State Server for storing Session in my application. The problem is that, when i hit my site and login in my site and after i login if i close my browser and reopen again thne my session is lost. I have to login in again. What is minimum do i have to do for making session alive even aftre closing browser.

My state server configuratin is below

```
 <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" />
```

and in my globel.aspx file on sesion_start i m doing this

```
// set the session timeout 20Minutes
    Session.Timeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeOutTimeInMinutes"].ToInt32Safe();
```

What is minimum do i have to do for making session alive even aftre closing browser.

[image: My State Server Sesstion]

Here is image of my settings on sever

Comment: I don't think that this is anything to do with how the session *state* is stored on the server side. The browser closing means that the session cookie is gone.

Comment: so what should i do to avoid that

Comment: Also keep in mind that in Asp.Net having a session and being logged in/authenticated are separate things. Usually a session is kept alive using a cookie. And authentication is also usually kept alive using a cookie. But they are different cookies, so you can lose you session while remaining logged in and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Session state uses non-persistent session cookies that (by design) do not survive when you close your browser. If you want persistent session state you need a means of making the ASP.NET session cookie persistent.

There are some examples out there. For example:

- [Create Persistent ID Cookies](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/security-development/create-persistent-id-cookies)
- [Persisting Session Between Different Browser Instances](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/06/09/persisting-session-between-different-browser-instances.aspx)
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004226/changing-expiry-on-asp-nets-session-state-cookie) has some useful comments and links too

Comment: Thanks!, in the third link was what i needed, working as a charm!